# Subset rows based on multiple iterative columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I need to subset rows of df based on several columns (c1 through c100 columns) which have strings. Subset rows which equal a particular value for any of the 100 columns.
Minimal example with 3 columns is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                     "c1": ["abc1", "", "dfg", "abc1", "","dfg","ghj","abc1","abc1"], 
                     "c2": ["abc1", "abc1", "dfg", "dfg", "","dfg","","ghj","abc1"], 
                     "c3": ["abc1", "", "dfg", "dfg", "dfg","dfg","abc1","ghj","abc1"]})
```

```
        c1      c2      c3
0   0   abc1    abc1    abc1
1   1           abc1    
2   2   dfg     dfg     dfg
3   3   abc1    dfg     dfg
4   4                   dfg
5   5   dfg     dfg     dfg
6   6   ghj             abc1
7   7   abc1    ghj     ghj
8   8   abc1    abc1    abc1
```

The loc command gives us the answer but too many 'or' conditions to write. I am looking for something iterative over 100 columns. Also what if I want to check for a list of strings instead of just 1 string. For example ['abc1', 'ghj'], instead of just 'abc1'.

```
df.loc[(df['c1'] == "abc1") | (df['c2'] == "abc1") | (df['c3'] == "abc1")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Searching for a single string

You can just check each "cell" with `df.eq('abc1')` or `df=='abc1'` and then take an `OR` over columns using `.any(1)` to check if each row has at least 1 instance of 'abc1'. Then use that boolean series for indexing the original data frame to get the rows you need.

```
output = df[df.eq('abc1').any(1)]

print(output)
```

```
        c1    c2    c3
0  0  abc1  abc1  abc1
1  1        abc1      
3  3  abc1   dfg   dfg
6  6   ghj        abc1
7  7  abc1   ghj   ghj
8  8  abc1  abc1  abc1
```

If you want to check only a specific set of columns then use `df[list_of_columns] == 'abc1'` instead.

---

#### 2. Searching for multiple strings

For multiple strings use `df.isin([list-of-strings])`. Here is an example of how that would work.

```
output = df[df.isin(['abc1', 'dfg']).any(1)]

print(output)
```

```
        c1    c2    c3
0  0  abc1  abc1  abc1
1  1        abc1      
2  2   dfg   dfg   dfg
3  3  abc1   dfg   dfg
4  4               dfg
5  5   dfg   dfg   dfg
6  6   ghj        abc1
7  7  abc1   ghj   ghj
8  8  abc1  abc1  abc1
```

---

#### 3. Searching for multiple strings across specific columns

If you want to search for multiple strings in a list of specific columns, you can just modify the previous `.isin` or `.eq` method with the list of columns filtered, and then continue the same method. Here is an example for the above script working for just 2 columns `c1` and `c3`

```
output = df[df[['c1','c3']].isin(['abc1','ghj']).any(1)]

print(output)
```

```
        c1    c2    c3
0  0  abc1  abc1  abc1
3  3  abc1   dfg   dfg
6  6   ghj        abc1
7  7  abc1   ghj   ghj
8  8  abc1  abc1  abc1
```

---

### References

Read more here on the official documentation -

- [Pandas eq method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)
- [Pandas isin method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: What to do to check two strings instead of just 1?

Comment: You can just use these as independent conditions. How many strings do you want to check?

Comment: Added another way for multiple strings.

Comment: Does my EDIT work for you? if yes, do mark the answer! thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I have added another edit for a handling multiple columns as well. do check!